# What is the command for finding the USB memory stick's mount point or path?

Tags: command-line, usb, mountpoint

I need to be able to retrieve just the USB memory stick's mount point or path. Is this the command for that? `lsblk -r | grep usb` I executed that command and it returns with the following. `sda1                /media/usb0` I just want the mount point or path to the memory stick.

Comment: Please do this instead, `sudo lsblk -l` make sure the usb is connected

Comment: Do you need it for a shellscript - for some automatic process, or is it enough to see and identify it with your eyes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with one for the command of `lsblk`.  It uses the options of MOUNTPOINT and HOTPLUG to help identify.  HOTPLUG returns a 1 if the drive is removable like a USB drive.  sr0 type drives are removable / hotplug, but those are CD/DVD drives.  And I also stop loop devices since they show that they are removable / hotplug too.

The command I came up with is the following:

```
lsblk -o NAME,HOTPLUG,MOUNTPOINT | grep -w 1 | grep -vE "sr|loop" | awk '{print $3}'
```

Which can produce the following results, as I have a USB drive in.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ lsblk -o NAME,HOTPLUG,MOUNTPOINT | grep -w 1 | grep -vE "sr|loop" | awk '{print $3}'

/media/terrance/E627-3C44
```

Which is the exact mount point of my USB drive plugged in.

**NOTE:** It looks as though Ubuntu 14.04 might not use the same options for `lsblk` so you can use the command with `RM` instead of `HOTPLUG`:

```
lsblk -o NAME,RM,MOUNTPOINT | grep -w 1 | grep -vE "sr|loop" | awk '{print $3}'
```

**Or**, you can use the `TRAN` type, I have tested in 16.04, which is `device transport type`.  Gives a different output that might be easier to script around.

```
lsblk -o NAME,TRAN,MOUNTPOINT
```

Which produces output like this:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ lsblk -o NAME,TRAN,MOUNTPOINT
NAME   TRAN   MOUNTPOINT
loop1         /snap/canonical-livepatch/17
sdb    usb    
└─sdb1        /media/terrance/E627-3C44
loop4         /snap/core/1441
sr0    sata   
loop2         /snap/core/1287
loop0         /snap/canonical-livepatch/21
sda    sata   
├─sda2        
├─sda5        [SWAP]
└─sda1        /
loop3         /snap/core/1337
```

Since the MOINTPOINT is listed on the next line after the usb, we will use `grep -A 1` to grab the next line and use `awk '{print $2}'` to print the second column of output on that line:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ lsblk -o NAME,TRAN,MOUNTPOINT | grep -A 1 -w usb | grep -v usb | awk '{print $2}'
/media/terrance/E627-3C44
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome answer. I didn't exactly follow your answer to retrieve just the mountpoint for my usb. However, your answer did help. I simply executed this command, `lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT | grep usb` and it returned with only the mount point for my usb. I did notice that HOTPLUG column did not exist in the possible column list.

Comment: @ThN As long as your usb drive is formatted with a label that contains the word usb you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Type:

df # shows the mount point for all known devices

In your case it will be something like:

/media/sr0

/media/usb0

I would NOT expect it to be sda1 which is typically the boot drive

Comment: No. I just want the mount point for my usb that is connected to the usb port. Thank you for your answer.